# multiple unrelated process synchronisation UART

Tags: c, linux, uart, synchronization

I want to use a shared library with multiple processes running concurrently. My library contains UART open/write/read/close, Each process writes a specific UART command and expects related response. Application calls APIs in LIB, Inside API open UART port, writes command to UART and read response from UART, process response buffer and send back to user [API takes 2 to 3 seconds for execution].

I have 30 such APIs and 5 processes running concurrently using these APIs.

How can I provide synchronisation across all these processes, such that only one process uses UART at a time and all other blocks on UART.

Regards & Thanks,
Anil.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking a very general question about how to co-ordinate multiple processes. This is a vast and deep subject, and there are lots of routes you could take. Here are some ideas:

1) [create a lock file in /var/lock](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.9.html). This will work with other programs that use the serial port. When one program is done, the others will race to create the lock, and a random one will win.

2) have your library create a [shared memory segment](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html). In the shared memory segment, write down who has the 'lock'. As with lock files, you'll want to write down the PID, so the others can steal the lock if the owner dies. This has the least amount of overhead.

3) Split your serial code into a "UART control daemon" and a client library that calls the daemon. The daemon listens on a unix socket (or TCP/UDP, or other IPC) and handles the serial port exclusively. (You can easily find 'chat server' code written in any language).  This has several advantages:

- The daemon can tell callers how many requests are "in the queue"
- The daemon can try to maintain the FIFO order, or handle priority requests if it wants.
- The daemon can cache responses when multiple clients are asking the same question at once.
- If you don't want the daemon running all the time, you can have xinetd start it. (Make sure it's in singe-server mode.)
- Instead of each process having to be linked to a serial library, it uses the simpler standard unix sockets (or TCP).
- Your API calling programs become much easier to test (no need for hardware, you can simulate responses)
- If an API calling program dies, the UART isn't left in a bad state